# electron-vite (react js) > react-router-dom not working

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-router-dom, vite

I created an electron app using `npm create @quick-start/electron` (react js). The `react-router-dom` library is working on development but not in the production.

They said that electron does not handle the browser history and I should use a `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`. https://evite.netlify.app/guide/troubleshooting.html#vue-router-or-react-router-dom-works-in-development-but-not-production

Does anyone know how to use the `HashRouter`?

I was expecting to make the `react-router-dom` work when I build the app.

edited

**CODE**

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

// libraries
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

// layouts
import PublicLayout from './layouts/PublicLayout'

// public pages
import Login from './pages/Public/Login'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/*" element={<PublicRoutes />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

export const PublicRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PublicLayout />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

**src>main>index.js**

```
mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'), { hash: 'login' })
```

Comment: `HashRouter` works *roughly* the same as the other routers. What specifically do you have a question about or need help with?

Comment: yes I tried to replace the BrowserRouter with HashRouter and added this 
mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'), { hash: 'home' }). but still not working. i'm using react-router-dom v6

Comment: Instead of wrapping your app component with `<BrowserRouter>`, you need to wrap it with `<HashRouter>`, or is there another problem?

Comment: Yes I did.

`ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)`

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you now also clarify what the issue is with using the `HashRouter`? Are there errors? Something not working as expected? Is there a problem?

Comment: the HashRouter doesn't work like BrowserRouter.

Comment: In which respect doesn't it work? Can you describe how it should work and how it actually behaves?

Comment: It is working now, I used the MemoryRouter instead of HashRouter. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

I used this convention for importing the react-router-dom components in App.tsx for my project. It worked when publishing the application or running npm start which runs --preview giving you a production preview of your application in a developers setting. I also needed to specify:

```
mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'), { hash: 'login' })
```

in src > main > index.ts

Comment: I just used MemoryRouter